# ASP.NET MVC как узнать как сейчас залогинен пользователь (IsPеrsistent)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Когда пользователь залогиневается на сайт ASP.NET MVC используя систему ASP.NET Identity, то во втором параметре `SignInManager.SignIn(user,IsPErsistent,false)` указывается запоминать пользователя или нет.
У меня такой вопрос, а как я могу узнать из кода сайта текущей пользователь в каком режиме залогинен.
Мне это надо так как я меняю имя пользователя и мне надо его перелогинить, но не понимаю откуда взять эту переменную.

Comment: IsPersistent=true выставляет у куки expire. false - не выставляет. можно попробовать покопать в эту сторону.

Comment: @PashaPash проверил куки, есть такой куки с именем 'ASP.NET_SessionId' и там Expire в обоих случаях стоит на {01.01.0001 0:00:00}

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

public static bool IsFormsAuthCookiePersistent()
{
  if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Request != null)
  {
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (cookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
    {
      try
      {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        return ticket.IsPersistent;
      }
      catch (Exception) { }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: О, круто! Я и не надеялся уже получить ответ. Буду в ближайшие дни пробовать и отпишусь как получилось.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` у меня не содержит `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName` , у меня так понял не FormsAuthentification. Вот такая строчка в конфиге есть `<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>` . Не знаю как этот тип аутентификации называется, но это стандартный проект с шаблона VS, с указанием Individual Users Accounts

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть на наличие "Experies date" у ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie".
Если дата установлено значить, "IsPErsistent = true"

Comment: И там и там ExpireDate стоит {01.01.0001 0:00:00}, или я что-то не так смотрю.

Comment: мда... почему та даже если установлено дата в куки, при чтение этого кукиса дата все равно по нулям.

Comment: наверно лучше установить еще один куки и дату определить такой же как куки при "Remember me" (устанавливаться App_Start/Startup.Auth/ app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            { ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(15)}), и проверят, если этот куки существует, значить "Remember me" включень

Comment: Да, можно так, или просто в базу данных записать. Я в базу данных записать хотел.

Comment: Вообще мне это нужно для смены имени пользователя, когда он в профиле меняет имя его надо перелогинить. Я уже знаю как это решить. Я его просто разлогиню, пусть сам заного логинится. Конечно это не самое красивое решение, но ситуация очень редкая со сменой имени, думаю для неё это решение вполне подходит.

Answer (score -3):

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{

}
else
{

]
```

Comment: Узнать можно из Request. Как в контроллере так и на представлении.

Comment: только вопрос не об этом :) вопрос о том, как проверить, выставлена постоянная кука (которая переживет рестарт браузера) или временная (которая умрет при рестарте). в обоих случаях Request.IsAuthenticated - true - пользователь же залогинен.

Comment: @PashaPash надо посмотреть какие куки на сайте в случае IsPersistent и какие в противном случае, может получится разобраться в чём разница